# UIButton inside cell programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

When I put a UIButton inside a cell class of a UICollectionView, who is the target? I can't set target to be "self", but it has to be the parent collectionView, in which I don't have a pointer to on the cell class..

```
//inside a cell class (`uicollectionviewcell`)


  [self.deleteCell addTarget:self action:@selector(clearCell:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

What should be instead of `self`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding the target in the collection it self on this method :

```
   - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Where i get into that button with `cell.button` , and add the target to self (which is the collection)